# Make absolute positioned span/div scrollable on android - more than one span/div

Tags: android, mobile, html, scroll, touch

I need help with a little problem I can't seem to get a grip to:

I have spans that show up on the bottom of the screen when I touch a character (a lot of characters -> a lot of spans). In the span are some information about the character - as I want to make it mobilefriendly I want the user to scroll throught that information.

So far I found a little bit code that helped me a little:

```
<body onload="touchScroll('test')">
<script>
function isTouchDevice(){
try{
    document.createEvent("TouchEvent");
    return true;
    }catch(e){
    return false;
   }
}

function touchScroll(id){
    if(isTouchDevice()){ //if touch events exist...
        var el=document.getElementById(id);
        var scrollStartPos=0;

        document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
        scrollStartPos=this.scrollTop+event.touches[0].pageY;
        event.preventDefault();
        },false);

        document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
        this.scrollTop=scrollStartPos-event.touches[0].pageY;
        event.preventDefault();
        },false);
    }
}
```

And the span with the id "test" becomes scrollable. Great. But as I have hundreds of span I can't assign an id to every single one. So I was wondering if you could help come up with a way to make every class "tt" scrollable.

I tried reassigning the "test"-id to the next element upon touch. But that didn't work. I tried adding the "test"-id to every class "tt" - didn't work either.

If you want to make yourself a picture of the situation: [Here's my testsite](http://p131548.webspaceconfig.de/mobilefirst/test.html)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on [this site](http://chris-barr.com/index.php/entry/scrolling_a_overflowauto_element_on_a_touch_screen_device/) in the comments:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
// Determine if this is a touch device
var hasTouch = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement,
startEvent = hasTouch ? 'touchstart' : 'mouseover',
moveEvent = hasTouch ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove',
endEvent = hasTouch ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup';

var Last;

$(".tttw").live(startEvent, function() {
if (Last) Last.removeClass('ttth');
$(this).addClass("ttth");
Last=$(this);
}); 

function isTouchDevice(){
try{
    document.createEvent("TouchEvent");
    return true;
}catch(e){
    return false;
}
}

function touchScroll(selector) {
if (isTouchDevice()) {
  var scrollStartPosY=0;
  var scrollStartPosX=0;
  $('body').delegate(selector, 'touchstart', function(e) {
    scrollStartPosY=this.scrollTop+e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
    scrollStartPosX=this.scrollLeft+e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
  });
  $('body').delegate(selector, 'touchmove', function(e) {
    if ((this.scrollTop < this.scrollHeight-this.offsetHeight &&
      this.scrollTop+e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY < scrollStartPosY-5) ||
      (this.scrollTop != 0 && this.scrollTop+e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY > scrollStartPosY+5))
          e.preventDefault();
    if ((this.scrollLeft < this.scrollWidth-this.offsetWidth &&
      this.scrollLeft+e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX < scrollStartPosX-5) ||
      (this.scrollLeft != 0 && this.scrollLeft+e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX > scrollStartPosX+5))
          e.preventDefault();
    this.scrollTop=scrollStartPosY-e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
    this.scrollLeft=scrollStartPosX-e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
  });
}
}


$(document).ready(function(){
touchScroll('.tt');
});

</script>
```

Working like a charm now ;-)